# Can't get Dapper to handle SQL RowVersion properly

Tags: c#, dapper, rowversion

I've got a rowversion column added to my database and I'm trying to get Dapper mapping to populate it properly on my object.

My object has...

```
public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
```

And I have included the RowVersion column in my query but when I do a Query..

```
conn.Query<MyObject, AnotherObject, AnAdditionalObject>(...
```

The MyObject that I get passed to me has a null for the RowVersion property.

If I do a Dapper Query() without any type then the dynamic I get back has the expected RowVersion on it with the correct value.

Has anyone had this working and if so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `rowversion` is an 8-byte number, not a byte array. Try changing the type to `ulong`. And post the query. It's not possible to verify the problem and check what's wrong without it

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos To be fair, `byte[]` is what you would use for EF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this thanks to the mental knock from Panagiotis Kanavos.  I started simplifying my query to be able to post it and realized that I had placed the RowVersion column in the incorrect place of my select statement so it was being sent to `AnotherObject` instead of MyObject

Thanks for that.

Comment: Dapper does work if the datatype is byte[] @ShaneCourtrille